# Como puedo crear un documento PDF con PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Hola buen día estoy buscando crear un documento pdf de un reporte que genero con php y mysql.

en mi consulta solo arrastro todos los datos del usuario y simplemente quiero pasarlos en el archivo pdf.

¿que herramienta podría usar para crear los documentos?

Comment: Te aconsejo buscar hacer busqueda en Google, Bing, o Yahoo sobre clases PHP para generar PDF, clases para generar PDF en PHP hay varias... Está [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/), [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), [ZEND PDF](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.create.html), y [PDFlib](http://www.pdflib.com/products/pdflib-family/). Desconozco si hay más, pero los mejores son los que te he mencionado. Espero puedas lograr lo que buscas.

Comment: usa la siguiente libreria https://mpdf.github.io/, la cual es perfecta para crear archivos pdf desde php

Answer (score 6):

Puedes usar la librería FPDF

Un ejemplo básico

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'¡Hola, Mundo!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Fuente: http://www.fpdf.org/